# How to match a shapefile with seconds as units with other layers

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have some shapefile in **coordinate seconds** (longitude & latitude multiplied by 3600).  I have open Google street layer by OpenLayers plugin in QGIS.

How to match my shapefile with Google street layer in correct position?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE but please don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: no. it's not duplicated. andre suggest me post a new thread alone. so i split question here.

Comment: Difference is that the units are in seconds, which is not covered by standard CRS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the transformation with GRASS `v.transform` using the Sextante toolbox in QGIS. This is how it works:

- Load the shapefile as WGS 84 `EPSG:4326`. Make sure this is also the **project** CRS. You better delete the openlayers Google layer until the transformation has finished.
- Install the sextante plugin
- Start `Analysis -> Sextante toolbox`
- Under GRASS commands, you find `v.transform`. If you do not have GRASS commands, you have to activate it in `Analysis -> Sextante options -> GRASS commands`
- Double-click it to open the dialogue
- For X Scale and Y Scale, enter 0.000277778 (which is 1/3600)
- leave all other parametres untouched
- Choose a new file name in the last field
- press OK to run.

You should see both layers, but have to zoom in to see the new layer within the  correct degrees range. After deleting the seconds layers, you can change the **project** CRS back to EPSG:3857 and add a Google layer again.

This works for points and line geometries. The qgsaffine plugin worked for me only with point layers (with the same scale values).